# Why bump questions from unregistered users

Tags: discussion

Why bump questions that are from unregistered users?

See [Need help to fix code P2138 on a 2007 ES Lancer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/61266/10976)

Comment: Are you asking why the algorithm bumps a post?

Comment: @BobCross sort of, but why not exclude the unregistered users as we seem to get so many bumped posts...

Answer (score 4):

The [purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279203/241919) of Community bumping unanswered questions (questions with no accepted/upvoted answers) is for users to review and take action if possible:

1. Is the question on-topic/answerable? Otherwise, flag/vote to close the question.
2. Are any answers helpful? Then, upvote them.
3. Are any answers bad? Then, downvote them.

It doesn't matter if the questions are from unregistered users or not because we only care about the content.